# Retrieve data from json resource with Retrofit2

Tags: android, json, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to make **item** POJO class with Retrofit. My json resource is confusing and it has a lot of item details. How do i make ?

```
{
"date" : "17-01-19",
"items": [
    {
        "id" : "123456789",
        "name" : "USA",
        "images": {
            "small": "https://www.google.com",
            "large": "https://www.google.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "id" : "123456789",
        "name" : "Finland",
        "images": {
            "small": "https://www.google.com",
            "large": "https://www.google.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "id" : "123456789",
        "name" : "Germany",
        "images": {
            "small": "https://www.google.com",
            "large": "https://www.google.com"
        }
    }

]
```

}

Comment: This is a pretty simple JSON.

Comment: That's example. Orginal json like this https://yts.am/api/v2/list_movies.json?sort_by=date_added

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Images {

@SerializedName("small")
public String small;
@SerializedName("large")
public String large;

}


package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Item {

@SerializedName("id")
public String id;
@SerializedName("name")
public String name;
@SerializedName("images")
public Images images;

}



package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Response {

@SerializedName("date")
public String date;
@SerializedName("items")
public List<Item> items = null;

}
```

or insted of `public Images images;` you can use `public Map<String,String> images;`

Answer (score 0):

A quick and automated way to create a POJO is to use a plugin for Android Studio.  Here's one I've used before:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8533-json2pojo

You basically copy and past your JSON to the plugin and it will auto generate your POJO for you.  For the most part, you can use it as is, or you can further tweak it.

Another alternative is this site:

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Tools like these are pretty helpful on more complex APIs.  Some times they're not 100% correct or require minor tweaking, but they do get most of the work done.